# Comparing two objects from the same type

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get all the fields that had been modified, comparing two objects from the same type.

For example:

```
public class Order
{
   public int OrderNumber {get;set;}
   public DateTime OrderDate {get;set};
   public string Something {get;set};
}
```

Then, I save a new Order:

```
Order order1 = new Order;
order1.OrderNumber = 1;
order1.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
order1.Something = string.Empty;

Save(order1)
```

After that, somebody tries to change some information from this order and I'm trying to find out the best way to get all the fields that were changed and save into a Log.

This must work for any type of two objects;

Should be a method like

```
public something ReturnFields(TObject objectSaved, TObject objectChanged)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Were you aware that Entity Framework does this for you?

Comment: Is there any problem with writing 3 If statements?

Comment: "must work for any type of two objects" - :) how would you define equality for two read-once object for example - like `NetworkStream`? Equality is harder topic than it looks...

Comment: Side note: consider to show some basic attempt implementing your requirement - getting list of fields via reflection and comparing one-by one via call to `.Equals` should give you a good starting point to think about all interesting corner cases.

Comment: I am not getting the two objects part.  If someone makes changes to this order then what does that have to do with comparing to another order?

Comment: I don't think you really mean "any type of two objects" - don't you mean "any two objects of the types that my program can work with"? I.e., your program works with different kinds of objects, but only objects that are designed to work with the program and the program is designed to work with? If so, I'd suggest that all these objects all be derived from a specific base object that contains a virtual method that all derived classes must implement, a method that compares fields and returns a list of modified fields. Or else they must all implement an interface that requires a method like that.

Comment: John, I am not using Entity. Just NHibernate. Do you know if NHibernate does the same?

Comment: RenniePet and Alexei Levenkov, when I said "any objects", I mean objects from my program, like Rennie said.

The idea of using Reflection seems to be the best idea, but I'm not familiar with that. Do you have any documentation about this case?

Comment: First, when you mention a person in a comment you should write @AlexeiLevenkov, just type @a and then select the name from the little popup. Then the person is notified. Otherwise the person may never come back here and see your comment.

Comment: Next, if we're talking a bout a limited number of different object types (<10?) with a limited number of fields (<10?), then I think reflection would be overkill. Just write the necessary methods, one method in each class, with a string of if statements, one if for every field. That would be my preference anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RenniePet
I will try some methods like you said. Maybe it is enough for this case. Meanwhile, I will read more about Reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the properties on an object, and build a series of expressions to compare each property. That way you can execute them, and for those that aren't equal, return their names to the caller.

It would need extending though if the property types themselves are not all value types as in your example, otherwise it would only be doing a check of reference equality.

```
public static class PropertyCompare<T>
{
    public readonly static Func<T, T, List<string>> ChangedProps;

    private class PropertyComparer<T>
    {
        public Func<T, T, bool> Compare { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    }

    static PropertyCompare()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        var firstObject = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
        var secondObject = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "b");
        PropertyComparer<T>[] propertyComparers = new PropertyComparer<T>[properties.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++) 
        {                        
            PropertyInfo thisProperty = properties[i];
            Expression arePropertiesEqual = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(firstObject, thisProperty), Expression.Property(secondObject, thisProperty));
            Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> equalityFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, bool>>(arePropertiesEqual, firstObject, secondObject);

            PropertyComparer<T> comparer = new PropertyComparer<T>()
            {
                Compare = equalityFunc.Compile(),
                PropertyName = properties[i].Name
            };

            propertyComparers[i] = comparer;                        
        }

        ChangedProps = new Func<T,T,List<string>>((a,b) =>
        {
            List<string> changedFields = new List<string>();

            foreach (PropertyComparer<T> comparer in propertyComparers)
            {
                if (comparer.Compare(a, b))
                    continue;
                changedFields.Add(comparer.PropertyName);
            }

            return changedFields;
        });
    }
}      

public class Order
{
   public int OrderNumber {get;set;}
   public DateTime OrderDate {get;set; }
   public string Something {get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Order myOrder1 = new Order() { OrderDate = DateTime.Today, OrderNumber = 1, Something = "bleh" };
    Order myOrder2 = new Order() { OrderDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), OrderNumber = 1, Something = "bleh" };
    List<string> changedFields = PropertyCompare<Order>.ChangedProps(myOrder1, myOrder2);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I created a project and it is working perfectly. I will try to use your idea in my project. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a log like txt you can make your function return's a string, like this bellow:

```
public string ReturnFields(TObject objectSaved, TObject objectChanged)
{

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

   if(!objectSaved.Name.Equals(objectChanged.Name)
   {

     sb.Append("Name was changed from " + objectSaved.Name  +" to: " + objectChanged.Name)

   }

   if(!objectSaved.OrderDate.Equals(objectChanged.OrderDate)
   {

   sb.Append("The date whas changed from " + objectSaved.OrderDate+" to: " + objectChanged.OrderDate)

   }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

It's just a simple way, you can read a little about Linq expressions to do it to.

Comment: It works if the objects would be always "Order". But I was thinking in something for Generic objects from my program